# How to execute a powershell script from a remote application as a specific user

Tags: windows, powershell, mappeddrive, net-use

I have an application which can execute a powershell script on remote windows machine. I am trying to map a network drive using a powershell script. When the same script executed at the endpoint, script works fine and able to map a network drive. But when the same script executed from my application, mapping a network drive done but as a disconnected network drive.

Now, my observations:
I found that My application is executing the script with `NT Authority\System` account. May be because of this, mapped network drive is visible to a specific user as a disconnected drive. am I correct!!?

Now, the problem:
What I can do to map a network drive available for all users? or
Can I run my powershell script as a specific user, sothat drive will be mapped to that user only?

Anyhow, I have already tried running my powershell script as a different user from my application using `Start-Process` and `Invoke-Command`, it  throws an error, says run `winrm quickconfig` which also did not work.

Any help? Appreciated!!

Comment: What is the Powershell version on the remote machine ? What OS and edition do you run there ?

Comment: It's Windows 7 SP1 professional edition, Default version of powershell, it is v1.0

Comment: @Pydev: I believe the default version of PowerShell on W7 is v2.0.

Answer (score 2):

When mapped from `NT Authority\System` the drive will show as disconnected, but it should work: [Map a network drive to be used by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service)

> NOTE: The newly created mapped drive will now appear for ALL users of
>   this system but they will see it displayed as "Disconnected Network
>   Drive (Z:)". Do not let the name fool you. It may claim to be
>   disconnected but it will work for everyone.

Moreover, mapping a drive using `NT Authority\System` is the only (although not officially supported) way to make a network drive available for all users.

If you want to map a drive for specific user, you'd have to [run PowerShell as a different user](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benshy/archive/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-amp-elevate-the-process.aspx). But it also means that you'd have to get credentials for that user.

This can be mitigated using token manipulation, but it's tricky. See [Invoke-TokenManipulation](https://github.com/clymb3r/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-TokenManipulation/Invoke-TokenManipulation.ps1) function and it's `ImpersonateUser` parameter.